# Attach image in a php form and use html2pdf

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

i have a php form and use html2pdf (TCPDF). The php form works when I use text and images that already include in the form, but now I want to attach a image and also include that in the pdf file.

The code I am using now I get the filename.

To attach the image I am using
`$<span><input type="file" name="foto"></span>`
And to include it in the pdf-file I use this code
`$foto = $_POST['foto'];`
`$content .= '<img src='.$foto.'with=200 height=auto>';`

Sorry for my bad English!
Regards
Daniel

Comment: Do an `var_dump()` on your $_POST variable ... you will see, that no image is set. You need an HTML-FORM `multipart/form-data` and in PHP you can read it with `$_FILE`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So I can't just wright`foto = $_FILES['foto'];` and to "print" it in the pdf file `$content .= '<img src='.$foto.'with=200 height=auto>';` or what should I wright?

Answer (score 0):

Do an normal HTML file upload like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Deine Datei ;) :
    <input name="fileUpload" type="file" accept="image/*"> 
  </label>  
  <label>Your Name:
    <input name="userName" type="text" accept="image/*"> 
  </label>
  <button type="submite" name="submite">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And on the PHP side you must move your file:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $userName = $_POST['userName']; // the normale methode
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
       $temp_path_to_file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];
       $file_content = file_get_contents($temp_path_to_file); 
       // and now past your image to your PDF.
       // if you want to save the image on the server you must move it with this (its not necessary if you want only to past it in your PDF)
       if(move_uploaded_file($temp_path_to_file, '/my/image/folder/image_'.uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
For your example you must convert the `$file_content` to an base64 string. Than you can past it in your image:

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . ';base64,' . base64_encode($file_content);
echo '<img src="'. $base64 .'" style="with: 200; height: auto">';
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help!
When I use the normal HTML file upload, how do I print it in the pdf file?
`'<img src="'. base64_encode($file_content) .'" style="with: 200; height: auto">';`
doesn't works.

Comment: "not work" is very unclear. What does not work? Did you do an `var_debug` on `$file_content`? Was there any content inside? Pls post your code here than we can help you better.

Comment: I have paste in the code you wrote for normal HTML file upload and the php code and deleted the last row `if(move_uploaded_file($temp_path_to_file, '/my/image/folder/image_'.uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` and when a do `var_debug` on `$file_content` I got many sign on the screen :) but when I paste `$content .='<img src="'. base64_encode($file_content) .'" style="with: 200; height: auto">';` the screen turns white when I press submit. The whole code can't fit, to many characters. Thank you again for helping me!

Comment: You are the best @Richard! When I update the image part and press submit the image that I want to attach in the pdf is showing in the top of the form and in the pdf it printed `data:image/;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQ.......`